# What's the best way to integrate SPI and MSC buses?

Tags: microcontroller, spi, adapter

I have two chips. The first chip has only an SPI interface. The second chip has only an [MSC](http://www.ip-extreme.com/IP/MSC.html) (microsecond channel) interface. What's the best way to integrate them? Do you know any IC manufacturer which has converters/adapters from SPI to MSC or vice versa? Should we create a custom SPI driver?

The first chip with SPI is [SAK-XC2388E-136F128L](http://www.infineon.com/search/en?q=SAK-XC2388E-136F128L&sd=PRODUCTS).

I can't disclose information about the second chip, but is it very important? I think it's more important that it has an MSC interface and we need to integrate SPI with MSC.

Comment: Everyone here loves links when "chips" are mentioned. Also when acronyms like [MSC](http://www.ip-extreme.com/IP/MSC.html) are mentioned.

Comment: In case Anindo's sarcasm doesn't trip your meter ( =] ), he's implying that you should add more information to your question so people will be more inclined to answer it.

Comment: thanks for your comments guys, i've added requested information.

Comment: This is a proprietary interface whose details are available only once you sign up or if (presumably) there is a NDA in place.  Tis is will be very difficult for someone to answer - either because they can't get the details necessary or if they have the details they may violate the terms of agreement(s).  This should be clarified before it can be answered.  Or at least provide unencumbered access to the datasheet.